# Update model from different ViewModels

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, controller, viewmodel

I have the following class in a .net core solution

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual Enum.ValidateStatus ValidateStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Mobile { get; set; }
    public virtual Enum.LoginType LoginType { get; set; }
    public virtual string PassWord { get; set; }

}
```

From that class i have created two ViewModels

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Mobile { get; set; }
}

public class AdminViewModel
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Enum.ValidateStatus ValidateStatus { get; set; }    
    public virtual Enum.LoginType LoginType { get; set; }
```

}

Im using the two models in forms and updating using a generic

```
    public class SaveData<T>
    {
        public async Task<T> Save(T saveItem, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(saveItem), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync("api/User/", content).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var stringResult = (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
                T result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(stringResult, options);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

My controller looks something like:

```
    public ActionResult<Comito.Core.Model.Entity.User> Post([FromBody] JsonDocument saveItem)
    {
        var saveUserViewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProfileViewModel>(saveItem.RootElement.ToString());
    }
```

In this version of the controller I assume that the passed model is ProfileViewModel, and thats the problem. Is there anyway i in the controller can discover which model has been sent.

I know I could create a controller for each model but thats not a way i will go.

Comment: Have you checked on JSON Schemas? This is the only way I think you could relate a JSON to an actual C# type. You can create schemas to describe your ViewModel objects, then schema validate it against the possible inputs and based on that define the Type to pass to deserialize.

Comment: Thx alot - I can't find any documentation for Schema Creation using System.Txt.Json, do I have to use NewtonSoft

Comment: Why not try to add a parameter to  action to save modelname?And use like this:`If(modelname=="ProfileViewModel"){var saveUserViewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProfileViewModel>(saveItem.RootElement.ToString());}else{var saveUserViewModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AdminViewModel>(saveItem.RootElement.ToString());}`